# "npm run dev" fails silently - nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

"npm run dev" fails silently while doing the initial setup of the next.js website

[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcOyu.png)

Node version: v13.13.0,
npm version: 6.14.4

After searching, I found [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6199) and tried this solution but it didn't resolve the issue. In this author suggested trying installing a canary version but the same problem faced with the canary version.

**To Reproduce**

- mkdir hello-next
- cd hello-next
- npm init -y
- npm install --save react react-dom next
- mkdir pages
- npm run dev

**System Information**
 - OS: windows
 - Browser: Chrome
 - Next.js: ^9.3.6-canary.1 / ^9.3.5" ( same problem in both versions )

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by @Christian in the comments

- There is nothing in debug logs
- After running npm run dev --verbose : [image: following logs are generated]

Comment: Tried it locally but could not reproduce it. Is any debug log file created in C:\Users\your-windows-user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\?

Comment: Looks like it is using `--silent` option by default :/ Have you tried `npm run dev --verbose`

Comment: @Christian thanks for the suggestion. After running npm run dev --verbose, in logs in logs we can see ignore-scripts is set to true. After setting it false it starts working. Thanks!!